# RNN input shape for sequence generation on Tensorflow

Tags: neural-networks

I would like to train a RNN with LSTM cells in Tensorflow to predict the next word of a sequence. Words are N-length vectors of 0s and 1s. By looking at different tutorials, I saw that the input tensor has a shape like this

```
seq_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [n_steps, batch_size, seq_width])
```

However, it is not clear to me what these shapes represent. How do I reshape my input words to match this shape?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  1. It might help to edit to link to one of the tutorials that has this.  2. I don't know if you're going to get any good answers here on CS.SE, because we tend to be focused more on concepts and algorithms than on code or specific libraries.  I suspect you'd be more likely to get a good answer on Stack Overflow.  Would you be happy with us migrating this question to Stack Overflow?

Comment: @D.W. Or even datascience.se.